# XCode Autocomplete of Int to intmax_t

Tags: swift, xcode, autocomplete

Can someone please help me fix this? It's getting real annoying when I'm trying to type fast and every time I declare an `Int` it tries to autocomplete to intmax_t...

I'm currently using Xcode 10 Beta 4 but I checked and the issue is in Xcode 9 as well.

[image: xcode autocomplete example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use `intmax_t` at all? When I start typing `Int` it shows up int to autocomplete. What I've noticed is that the more you type a word and select it to autocomplete that would will show up first to auto complete. I would try selecting `Int` a few times in the autocomplete list that way it should change to recommend  `Int` instead on `intmax_t`

Comment: I've never used it nor do I even know when I ever would lol.
That being said just spamming `Int` repeatedly seemed to fix it though. Thanks.